# How could this assembly be possible?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

```
int sarl_n(int x, char n){
   x <<= 2;
   x >>= n;
   return x;
```

}

When I assemble with "gcc -m32 -S sarl_n.c", it emits this code:

```
.cfi_startproc
movl    4(%esp), %eax
movsbl  8(%esp), %ecx
sall    $2, %eax
sarl    %cl, %eax    #This is the part which I don't understand
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

Why is gcc using the "mini register" `%cl` instead of the big one `%ecx`?

EDIT: I used the O2 option to get shorter assembly code

Comment: It's for optimization purposes I guess: 8-bit long %cl is better to store small results than a 16-bit %ecx.

Comment: Try assembling it with the `-O2` option to receive a more sensible output.

Comment: @kiner_shah: I doubt that it's for _optimization purposes_, because without the `-Ox` option it won't get optimized(much). I suppose that it's the raw output of some transformation blocks.

Comment: @zx485, I don't know the commands, but compiler must try to generate as much optimal assembly code as it could, so maybe that's why %cl appeared there! N you are actualy right, it may be the raw output!

Comment: @zx485 I edited with the O2 option

Comment: Simple: that's the only version of the instruction that exists. See the instruction set reference. In any case, the count is masked so it doesn't matter.

Comment: The instruction shifts `eax` right by the number of places in `cl`. Since the maximum useful size of the shift is 32 (actually by the C standard I think it can only be 31)  for a 32-bit int, the instruction doesn't need a full width register. Only 5 bits are needed, so the engineers at Intel used an 8-bit register. There's probably some legacy considerations, too. `cl` has been used for shift counts since 8086 days (late 70's).

Comment: @Gene: The shift count is masked to the 0..31 range (or 0..63 when operand-size = 64-bit).  See [the SAR insn set ref manual entry](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html).  Anyway, the key point is that `%cl` is an implicit operand in the machine code: there are no bits that mean "cl", other than the opcode itself.  There's no way the compiler could have used any other register, except with BMI2 [`SARX r32_dest, r/m32_src, r32_count`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SARX:SHLX:SHRX.html), which it would use if you'd enabled `-march=haswell` or `-mbmi2`.

Comment: @kiner_shah That's not correct. Please do not comment with speculation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why the following line(previous version) in question

```
sarl    %cl, 8(%ebp)    #This is the part which I don't understand
```

or (current version)

```
sarl    %cl, %eax       #This is the part which I don't understand
```

is using the `%cl` and not `%ecx` is, that the `SAR` opcode only supports the `%cl` register as an input for a variable arithmetic shift(by `%cl` times).

See [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html), and I quote:

```
SAR r/m32, CL     MC   Valid   Valid   Signed divide* r/m32 by 2, CL times.
```

Comment: I would understand that if the part of r/m32 were r/m8 ... because r/m32 means registers of 32 bits, right?

Comment: Yes. `r/m32` does mean a 32-bit memory-address(like `8(%ebp)` in your previous version) or a 32-bit register(like `%eax` in the current version). `CL` is _Intel syntax_ for _AT&T syntax_ `%cl`. _AT&T_ syntax also inverts the source/destination order. So `sarl %cl, %eax` in _AT&T_ syntax is `SAR EAX, CL` in _Intel syntax_.